# How to open unknown structure database with entity framework 4

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I've 'Googled' and 'Binged' for all the Web trying to solve this problem...
I had no success so I returned to ADO.NET 4.x to continue my work

I have a program in which the user can select and open any database...
The tables, views, stored procs, etc. of the select database are shown in a tree so the user can click a node and view/edit data in a grid.

After struggling a few times with EF4 (DB First, Model First, Code First, etc.) I cant find a way to at runtime generate the entities for the user selected database...

Anyone can provide extra Info... maybe sample code ???

Comment: The advantages of Entity Framework are pretty much moot if you're not writing code against a specific data structure. It is an Object-Relational Mapper, and you appear to only be interested in the Relational part of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Entity Framework (like any other ORM) is used to map a data model to a logical model. If there's no mapping (and no logical model), there's no Entity Framework.

ADO is the way to go in this case.

After some questionning, it is possible to do it, but it involves crazy steps.

To do it, you'd have to generate the edmx xml from the informations you'll get by querying the master database, from this xml generate the classes (data context and entities) at runtime, load them in your AppDomain through code dom, and then you could use this dynamically generated data context through Entity Framework.

In one sentence : for this kind of scenario where you data model is totally unknown and changing, stick to good ol' ADO.NET. It's tailored for this.

Comment: Hi Guillaume...
Hearing the Microsoft Marketing EF is the future...
For the tests I made... for the Architecture new (ObjectContext+ObjectSets)... and for the Conceptual Model... I'm persuaded of this!
If you digg into the Code and Framework you can see that with a plethora ok work you can generate lots of things at runtime and make it work...
Well, I dont want to loose this time and made a NON-STANDARD library and then find that Microsoft supported this...
This is a very important matter... maybe it's a lot undocumented... I hope some EF-Guru can Enlight us all about this...
Thanx. ~ZEE~

Comment: The thing is, what you're wanting to do is the contrary of the spirit of EF (and ORM based technologies). An ORM is a way to work with your logical domain at the center of your work. What you want to do is having your data drive your model.

Comment: Sometimes we don't know the model and we want to work woth data... something like a **DB editor** will have to work this way. Also with .net4 dynamica objects this seems possible... read the schema os a database and generate dynamic objects with the info obtained. I'll keep watching for this... I'm trying to leave ado... ORM's are more pratical and the natural data<->object relation is better.